# Why this function is not able to reverse the Linked List?

Tags: c++, struct, reverse, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I want to reverse a linked list but when i compile this code it terminates unexpectedly.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class node{
public:
    int data;
    node* next;

    node(int val){
    data=val;
    next=NULL;
        }
};
```

For Inserting Elements in Linked List

```
void insertattail(node* &head,int lol){
    node* n= new node(lol);
    if(head==NULL){
        head=n;
        return;
    }
    node* temp=head;
    while(temp->next!=NULL){
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    temp->next=n;
}
```

Display Function to print linked list

```
void display(node* head){
    node* temp =head;
    do{
        cout<<temp->data<<"->";
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    while(temp!=NULL);
    cout<<"Null";

}
```

Function to reverse Linked List

```
node* reverseit(node* head){
    node* prevptr= NULL;
    node* currptr= head;
    node* nextptr= currptr->next;
    while(currptr!=NULL){
        currptr->next =prevptr;
        prevptr=currptr;
        currptr=nextptr;
        nextptr=currptr->next;
    }
    return prevptr;
}
```

Main Function

```
int main()
{
    node* head= NULL;
    insertattail(head,1);
    insertattail(head,2);
    insertattail(head,3);
    insertattail(head,8);
    node* newhead= reverseit(head);
    display(newhead);
    return 0;
}
```

I think the problem is in logic of reverse function.
I just used the code for linked list and made small changes.

Comment: dont make us make assumptions about your code. Instead assume that we know nothing about the code you do not show us, hence all code necessary to reproduce the issue has to be included in the quesiton. Read about [mcve]

Comment: It fails immediately on the empty list.

Comment: No, we cannot assume that "all other functions are correct". Just because this is where the program crashes or reports an error doesn't mean this is where the problem is. C++ does not work this way. The problem can be elsewhere, but after the bug occurs the program keeps running until it crashes here. This is why stackoverflow.com's [help] requires you to show a [mre] that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, then compile, run, and reproduce your problem. See [ask] for more information. Until you do that, it is unlikely that anyone will be able to figure out your problem.

Comment: Whst did you debugger tell you?

Comment: Also, why is this tagged `c++`? There are no C++ features visible.

Comment: Assume that `nextptr` is the null pointer (that is, you have reached the last node of the list), then think about what happens in `currptr=nextptr; nextptr=currptr->next;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initialization and 'incrementing' of `nextptr` both (potentially/eventually) dereference a `NULL` value of `currptr`. You should initialize `nextptr` to `NULL` and only change that to the 'real' next if `currptr` is not `NULL`; thus, its (re)assignment should be at the **start** of the loop, not at the **end**:

```cpp
node* reverseit(node* head){
    node* prevptr = nullptr;
    node* currptr = head;
    node* nextptr = nullptr; // Don't assume a non-NULL currptr
    while (currptr != nullptr) {
        nextptr = currptr->next; // Safe here: save next
        currptr->next = prevptr; // Do the reversal here
        prevptr = currptr;       // Step forward through
        currptr = nextptr;       // the list (prev/curr)
    //  nextptr = currptr->next; // WRONG HERE: currptr will be NULL at some point
    }
    return prevptr;
}
```

Comment: ok So the thing is if our currptr is null we can't do nextptr=currptr->next; right?

Comment: @SaranshKumar Exactly. Attempting to dereference a null pointer is undefined behaviour. It nearly always causes a program to crash.

Answer (score 0):

The function invokes undefined behavior.

For example let's at first assume that the list is empty. That is the pointer `head` is equal to `nullptr`. In this case using this line before the while loop within the function

```
node* nextptr= currptr->next;
```

accesses memory using a null pointer.

Or let's consider another example when `current->next` is equal to `nullptr`. In this case `nextptr` will be equal to `nullptr` and within the while loop these statements

```
    currptr=nextptr;
    nextptr=currptr->next;
```

again access memory using a null pointer.

And declarations of many pointers before the while loop

```
node* prevptr= NULL;
node* currptr= head;
node* nextptr= currptr->next;
```

makes the code less readable and clear.

The function can be defined the following way

```
node * reverseit( node *head )
{
    node *new_head = nullptr;

    for ( node *current = head; head != nullptr; head = current )
    {
        current = head->next;
        head->next = new_head;
        new_head = head;
    }

    return new_head;
}
```

If actually your program is a C program then instead of `nullptr` use `NULL`.

Also in main there is no need to introduce the new pointer `newhead`

```
node* newhead= reverseit(head);
```

You could just write

```
head = reverseit(head);
```

The function `display` can again invoke undefined behavior if the passed pointer to the head node is equal to `nullptr`. And the parameter of the function should have the qualifier `const` because within the function the list itself is not changed.

The function can be defined the following way

```
std::ostream & display( const node *head, std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    for ( const node *current = head; current != nullptr; current =current->next )
    {
        os << current->data << " -> ";
    }

    return os << "Null";
}
```

And the function can be called like

```
display( head ) << '\n';
```